# Sort boxplot by mean (and not median) in R

Tags: r, sorting, boxplot, mean

I have a simple boxplot, showing the distribution of a score for factor TYPE:

```
myDataFrame = data.frame( TYPE=c("a","a","b","b","c","c"), SCORE=c(1,1,2,3,2,1) )
boxplot( SCORE~TYPE, data=myDataFrame )
```

The various types are shown in the order they have in the data frame.
I'd like to sort the boxplot by the **mean** of SCORE in each TYPE (in the example above, the order should be `a,c,b`).

Any hint?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is a job for [`reorder()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/stats/html/reorder.factor.html):

```
myDataFrame$TYPE <- with(myDataFrame, reorder(TYPE, SCORE, mean))
boxplot( SCORE~TYPE, data=myDataFrame )
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks! When TYPE is as a string (`t = "TYPE"`), `myDataFrame[,t] <- with(myDataFrame, reorder(myDataFrame[,t], SCORE, mean))` works nicely.