# Does unique() preserve order?

Tags: r

Imagine we're using the following code:

```
set.seed(42)
v <- sample(1:10, 100, T)
v <- sort(v)
unique.v <- unique(v)
```

Can I be sure that `unique.v` is already sorted?

In a more general setting, is that true that `unique()` returns a vector, ordered according to the first entry?

The documentation does not imply this, looking to the source with

```
?unique
getAnywhere('unique.default')
```

is not of a much help.

Related questions: [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20127407/re-order-y-axis-by-number-of-observations/20244137#20244137), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10782403/show-source-code-for-function-in-r).

Comment: Regarding related question two: [this FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19226816/how-can-i-view-the-source-code-for-a-function) will help you more.

Comment: you want to see `methods(unique)`. specifically `unique.data.frame`, `unique.matrix`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here's what I found.
[This](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2006-4.pdf) guide leads us to [names.c](http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/main/names.c), where we see

```
{"unique",  do_duplicated,  1,  11, 4,  {PP_FUNCALL, PREC_FN,   0}},
```

After that we move to [unique.c](http://svn.r-project.org/R/trunk/src/main/unique.c) and find an entry

```
SEXP attribute_hidden do_duplicated(SEXP call, SEXP op, SEXP args, SEXP env)
```

Browsing the code, we stumble upon

```
dup = duplicated3(x, incomp, fL, nmax);
```

which is a reference to

```
static SEXP duplicated3(SEXP x, SEXP incomp, Rboolean from_last, int nmax)
```

Finally, the main loop here is

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
//      if ((i+1) % NINTERRUPT == 0) R_CheckUserInterrupt();
        v[i] = isDuplicated(x, i, &data);
}
```

So the answer to my question is **yes**.